# query email, name, ip_address, referrer, user_agent, path

Tags: mysql, join, right-join

so I have this query but I want a result like this

| email | name | ip_address | referrer | user_agent | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john@test.com | John | 127.0.0.1 | google.com | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.3 | sample1.png |
|  |  |  |  |  | sample2.png |
|  |  |  |  |  | sample3.png |
| john@test.com | John | 127.0.0.1 | google.com | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.3 | sample1.png |
|  |  |  |  |  | sample2.png |
|  |  |  |  |  | sample3.png |

### SQL query

```
SELECT u.*,
case when m.meta_key = "ip_address" then m.meta_value end as ip_address,
case when m.meta_key = "referrer" then m.meta_value end as referrer,
case when m.meta_key = "user_agent" then m.meta_value end as user_agent,
i.url_path
FROM tbl_users AS u  
RIGHT JOIN tbl_users_meta AS m ON m.user_id = u.id
RIGHT JOIN tbl_users_images AS i ON m.user_id = i.id
```

### Output

| id | email | name | ip_address | referrer | user_agent | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john@test.com | John | 127.0.0.1 |  |  | sample1.png |
| 1 | john@test.com | John |  | google.com |  | sample1.png |
| 1 | john@test.com | John |  |  | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.3 | sample1.png |
| 2 | jane@test.com | jane | 127.0.0.1 |  |  | sample2.png |
| 2 | jane@test.com | jane |  | google.com |  | sample2.png |
| 2 | jane@test.com | jane |  |  | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.3 | sample2.png |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | sample3.png |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | sample4.png |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | sample5.png |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | sample6.png |

## for tables

> -- create 
> CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> email TEXT NOT NULL,
> name TEXT NOT NULL
> );

> -- insert 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users VALUES (0001, 'john@test.com', 'John'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users VALUES (0002, 'jane@test.com', 'Jane');

> -- create 
> CREATE TABLE tbl_users_meta (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> user_id INTEGER,
> meta_key TEXT NOT NULL,
> meta_value TEXT NOT NULL
> );

> -- insert 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_meta VALUES (0001, 1, 'ip_address',   '127.0.0.1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_meta VALUES (0002, 1, 'referrer', 'google.com'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_meta VALUES (0003, 1, 'user_agent',   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.3'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_meta VALUES (0004, 2, 'ip_address',   '127.0.0.1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_meta VALUES (0005, 2, 'referrer', 'google.com'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_meta VALUES (0006, 2, 'user_agent',   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.3');

> -- create 
> CREATE TABLE tbl_users_images (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> user_id INTEGER,
> url_path TEXT NOT NULL
> );

> -- insert 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_images VALUES (0001, 1,   'sample1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_images VALUES (0002, 1,   'sample1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_images VALUES (0003, 1,   'sample1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_images VALUES (0004, 2,   'sample1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_images VALUES (0005, 2,   'sample1'); 
> INSERT INTO tbl_users_images VALUES (0006, 2,   'sample1');

Comment: Would you settle for something like `sample1.png,sample2.png` in the final column? If so, look into `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: my client don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT 
    t.email, t.name, t.ip_address, t.referrer, t.user_agent, 
    i.url_path 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        u.*,
        (SELECT mip.meta_value FROM tbl_users_meta AS mip WHERE mip.meta_key = "ip_address" AND mip.user_id = u.id) AS ip_address,
        (SELECT mref.meta_value FROM tbl_users_meta AS mref WHERE mref.meta_key = "referrer" AND mref.user_id = u.id) AS referrer,
        (SELECT magent.meta_value FROM tbl_users_meta AS magent WHERE magent.meta_key = "user_agent" AND magent.user_id = u.id) AS user_agent
    FROM tbl_users AS u 
)
AS t
LEFT JOIN tbl_users_images AS i ON t.id = i.user_id;
```

And output of above would be:
[image]